# How to detect whether a remote computer is running RDP?

Tags: desktop, protocols, detect, rdp

**How do I detect if a remote client is running Remote Desktop Protocol? and it is also accepting remote desktop connections ??**

Like Open an port to detect HTTP and send request, receive request headers and see in request headers information about HTTP so I will know the person is running HTTP weather if he changed the port e.g: running HTTP 6551.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Attempt and make a connection with something that is RDP-connection aware*** (RDP is not HTTP). Of course, failing to establish an initial handshake is not proof that a connection can not be established. It could be blocked by a firewall, listening on another port, etc.

[The MS-RDPBCGR specification, page 16 talks about connecting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc240445%28PROT.10%29.aspx) which in turn defers to X.224, go figure.

It'd likely just be easiest to [use Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org) and observe in-the-wild behavior to develop a minimal detection case. I suspect only the very initial portion of the handshake needs to be generated/replayed in order to "decide" that it's a listening RDP server.

(Or, perhaps use an existing RDP client which has this "test connect" functionality or the ability to be scripted.)

Answer (score 3):

A fast way is to pen a shell and type

```
telnet IPADDRESS 3389
```

If you get a connection, chances are good that an RDP server is on the other side. RDP can run on any port, but TCP Port 3389 is set per default.

Windows 7 requires [some extra steps](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/910.how-to-enable-telnet-client-in-windows-7.aspx) to enable the telnet Client.

Answer (score 2):

You could do **netstat -a** in the command line and see if the default port for remote desktop connection is listening, ie. **TCP:3389** but thats only if the client hasn't changed the ports for MSTSC

Comment: i am not sure how it can be done by implementing a program, i am not doubting the fact, just never thought about it. If the purpose is to connect to a computer that you can physically touch, I suggest you should try either through the command line tools or just viewing the remote settings.